# webpage height is stretched in mobile safari

Tags: html, ios, css, iphone, mobile-safari

I have created a website and it works fine on all platforms except mobile safari, where the page height is stretched and after the first click page become unresponsive.

```
html,body {
  height:100%;
  background:center no-repeat fixed url('../asset/images/logo1.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  color:#444;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}
```

My meta tags:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0">
```

**Edit:**
[Website in question](http://www.healthfriends.in)

Comment: Try to use height: 100vh; instead of 100%

Comment: No effect, @Sunny please check the website.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is that the frameset is deprecated, and its no wonder that its causing issue on safari of iPhone. Please see - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/frameset.

Second - why do you need to do 100% body and html height? Even if you want the height to be minimum 100%, then do min-height:100vh for the body.

Third - Even the frameset is not being used properly. You are including the contents of the website - http://satyam.esy.es/HealthFriends/ into the website - http://healthfriends.in/. So why not copy paste the contents and assets as there are no extra frames in the frameset.

Last - If you cannot pull assets from the domain satyam.esy.es then there could be a problem, that you will have to develop assets by yourself. In that case too, make cdn requests for bootstrap, datepicker and moment.js. And write your own css and js.

About your issue of iPhone- Of course framesets are causing issue. But there could be something else too. You need to use [Mordenizr](https://modernizr.com/) to check what features work for safari iOS, and then use proper polyfills.

Hope this helps you debugging and developing. Thanks

Comment: Thanks @vineet for pointing out the frame sets, those are indeed creating problem. however am still looking for solution. Since the frame set is not added by me but are somehow rendered in my code (magic ,i know). 
Need to find a way to either eliminate them or adjust them with changing os.

Comment: what's your technology stack?

Comment: HTML, Bootstrap with jQuery and php

Comment: As it turns out, when ever we use froward with masking ,the rendering domain is encapsulated in a frame. This in turn creates problem since frames are not too flexible with changing browser height and width.
I still want to stick with (free hosting) forwarding since i can't afford a hosting just yet.
This is the reason my webpage is behaving weird on iPhone.

Comment: So are you saying that http://satyam.esy.es/HealthFriends/ is made in some different language than php? If it's the case then no one can help, else you should make your website in the same domain.